# GWT TextArea Event Listener

Tags: java, gwt, listener

I am going to try to add a listener but i don't know what to do.

I want to execute a function after the user finish inputting text.

For example, a user input text "123" in to my TextArea and use mouse to click outside , or click another field / whatever.

What listen should i use in GWT?

I don't know the keywords of the listener so i come here for help.

The Code i had try it simply, actually i don't think it helps a lot if i provide the coding since i only don't know what listener / how to make the function i want.

```
private TextArea TextAreaPartA;
TextAreaPartA = new TextArea();
TextAreaPartA.setFieldLabel("PartA");
TextAreaPartA.setSize(500, 40);
//TextAreaPartA.onComponentEvent(ce);
```

Comment: use addBlurHandler..

Comment: but my TextArea didn't having this choice...

Comment: .try addblurhandler..see the below code which i have posted

Answer (score 0):

You can try [addBlurHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasBlurHandlers.html#addBlurHandler(com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.BlurHandler))

```
TextAreaPartA.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler()
{
            @Override
            public void onBlur(BlurEvent event)
            {
                         //do stuff
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AddBlurHandler,

```
TextArea area=new TextArea;    
 area.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onBlur(final BlurEvent event) {
                // Do the Stuff here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`addBlurHandler()` does not work because it seems like you are not using the actual GWT TextArea (I think you use the TextArea from GwtExt). Please check your import, it should be `import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;`

Please also note that you should start variable names lowercase.